# I wana display just 10 rows per page.But i don't know how?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I used this code its working fine and displaying all the employees in single page.. It doesn't looks good. So I want 10 employees per page and when I click on next next 10 has to display .This is exactly I want. Please help me

```
angular.module('picassoApp')
  .controller('AdminCtrl', function($scope, $http, $location) {
    $scope.employees =

      $http.get("api/employee")
      .success(function(response) {
        $scope.employees = response;
      })
      .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("Error" + status);
      });
  });
```

Comment: Please don't use snippets for code that isn't supposed to run in the question.

Comment: There isn't out-of-the-box solution for this. I've recently faced the same issue and built something, but it's quite complex. Feel free to try something yourself first, and if stuck ask for guidance

Comment: you can use for this bootstrap datatables

Comment: Otherwise here is the example. Have a look http://plnkr.co/edit/Wtkv71LIqUR4OhzhgpqL?p=preview

Comment: @Deepaksaini but then dynamic contents would be lost, e.g. if there are actions to be done in each row, not only show the data. (for example, letting user edit)

Comment: I think you have to do it server side like this: $http.get("api/employee",{ params : {
                        pageSize : pageSize})

Comment: No dynamic contents never be lost. It will be functional with datatables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some solutions that you need to think and apply as per your application's requirement.

1. You are making AJAX call here. If you really need to call AJAX on every page change on "Next" button click, then your server side code need to change accordingly and need to send the Page number on each call. But seems it is not your solution because you want this for screen look and feel.
2. Pagination on client side is just suitable for you. Capture the response and put it on a variable, say employees. Then use angular filter **limitTo** as follows on ng-repeat.

   {{ employees  | limitTo : rowLimit : rowStart}}

then change the rowStart on Next Button event with +10 or -10
and also do not forget to define the following on Controller initialization.

```
 $scope.rowLimit = 10;
 $scope.rowStart = 0;
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to this.

First, if you control the API, you can change it to return paged results. Then, instead of calling just `$http.get("api/employee")` you'd have to call something like `$http.get("api/employee?page=0")`.

If you have no control over the API, however, you may use client side paging using the angular's limitTo filter (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo).
Your controller would stay mostly the same, you'd have to modify the view by adding the filter to your ng-repeat (e.g. `ng-repeat="employee in employees | filter:10:startIndex`, assuming you have the `startIndex` scope variable determining which item to start with).